# angular 1.6.4 routing not working

Tags: angularjs

Working on a project, but the routes don't seem to working for me. I tried '#!/' and '#'.   Below is my code for the same. I am using angular 1.6.4. 
Home page url is localhost/ang/index.htm, after click on about link url becomes localhost/ang/index2.htm#about. Required URL : localhost/ang/about

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script >

        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

        myApp.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function (e, r) {
            r.hashPrefix('');
            r.html5Mode(true);
            e.when('/', {   templateUrl : 'red.html',   controller  : 'mainController'  })
            .when('/about', {   templateUrl : 'blue.html',  controller  : 'aboutController' })
            .when('/contact', { templateUrl : 'green.html', controller  : 'contactController' });
        }]);

        myApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
            $scope.message = 'Test';
        });

        myApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
            $scope.message = 'Test';
        });

        myApp.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
            $scope.message = 'test';
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainController" ng-app="myApp">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Angular Routing Example</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="main">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I tried many solutions provided on Stackoverflow but not working for me.

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working?

Comment: home page url is http://localhost/ang/index.htm, after click on about link url becomes http://localhost/ang/index2.htm#about.
Required URL : http://localhost/ang/about

Comment: Do you see any error ?

Comment: no error in console

Comment: @AkhileshKumar Check the answer below with working plunker. I will suggest you to remove r.hashPrefix(''); from your application in your localhost and it will work. Add it back when you deploy the application live.

Comment: i tried with '#' , '#!', '#!/' and '/' but finally solution was without these 4 in href...

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your code is not working is because you have not mentioned any base href for your application. You can either remove `r.html5Mode(true);` or add a base href to make your application work. But I suggest you to remove `r.html5Mode(true);` from your localhost configuration. And add it back along with a base href while you deploy your code to production.

**HTML**:

```
<base href="/ang/">
<!-- Give a base Url for your application -->

<body ng-controller="mainController" ng-app="myApp">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Angular Routing Example</a> </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="main">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JS**:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
myApp.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function(e, r) {
    r.hashPrefix('');
    r.html5Mode(true);
    e.when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'red.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    }).when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'blue.html',
        controller: 'aboutController'
    }).when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: 'green.html',
        controller: 'contactController'
    });
}]);
myApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Test';
});
myApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Test';
});
myApp.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'test';
});
```

**Working Plunker**: https://plnkr.co/edit/rPr4atjkuxnCwissmdl3?p=preview

Comment: Plunker link is working for me. let me check where i was wrong. Thanks for the solution.